# say verb not executing inside gather verb with twilio and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I make an outgoing call with call_phone, then when it's answered, I ask the user to "Please press one to continue". If they don't press any digits before the timeout. I ask a second time and say "I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue."

call_phone() works and redirects to communications_digits_path when the user answers. I hear "Please press one to continue" and if I press one on the phone keypad. The call redirects to communications_menu_path.

The problem is, if I don't press any phone key, instead of playing "I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue.", the call just hangs up. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
def call_phone(phone_number)
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(
    Rails.application.secrets.twilio_voice_sid,
    Rails.application.secrets.twilio_token
  )
  @call = @client.account.calls.create(
    from: Rails.application.secrets.twilio_voice_number,
    to: phone_number,
    url: communications_digits_path,
  )
end

def digits
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say "Please press one to continue", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
    r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: communications_menu_path do |g|
      g.say "I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue."
    end
  end
  render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue is that you have a lower case "s" for your second [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say).

But in general, we could make this a bit more robust with a couple of changes. Firstly, if the user were to press one while the first message was still playing then nothing would happen as it is not within the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). Secondly, we can [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) between the two messages to give the user a chance.

Try something like:

```
def digits
  twiml_response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Gather numDigits: '1', action: communications_menu_path do |g|
      g.Say "Please press one to continue", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
      g.Pause length: 5
      g.Say "I didn't get any response. Please press one to continue.", voice: 'alice', language: 'an-AU'
    end
  end
  render :xml => twiml_response.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if that helps.